# Updating to Spring 3.X from 2.X - Correct way to replace deprecated method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to migrate to spring 3. I am finding that many method like csrf, authorizeReuqests, antMatcher has been deprecated.

What is the correct way to replace them?

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers(apiPublicPattern).permitAll().antMatchers(fileExtensions)
                .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(compositeAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/expired").sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());
        http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()).and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").and().headers().contentSecurityPolicy(contentSecurityPolicy);
        http.authenticationProvider(jwtBearerTokenAuthenticationProvider());
        http.authenticationProvider(apiKeyAuthenticationProvider());
        return http.build();


    }
```

IDE shows warnings[image]

Comment: Did you look at the documentation? That should tell you what you need to know.

Comment: see https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/deprecated-list.html perhaps?

Comment: why did you not read the documentation?